# Changing directory in files with sed command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

So this should be simple, but I am stuck changing the directories written inside a bunch of GDML files. So I define the address to be replaced as `jk=":http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd"`

and the replacement as `kj="/home/shirin/TPS/Geant4/geant4.10.02.p02/source/persistency/gdml/schema/gdml.xsd"`

then I do
`sed -i 's@jk@kj@' 60000222.gdml` and the directory typed in the `60000222.gdml` does not change. Hence, `sed` does not work in this case, or I am making a rather stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replace a literal `jk`, then there are no matches.

Try

```
sed -i "s@${jk}@${kj}@" 60000222.gdml
```